# Deep linking not working on other browsers, except Chrome

Tags: android

I am receiving an email from my app that contains a button which should redirect me back to my app when tapped. The problem is that it seems to work only when my default browser is Chrome. When I set Samsung Internet as default browser the link is opened directly in browser.

In AndroidManifest I have

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:pathPrefix="/redirect-link" />
            <data android:host="www.myapp.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I've seen many posts suggesting to use a URI scheme fallback mechanism but I do not have such thing. The button from the email only contains a web URL. Is there any other approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

> When I set Samsung Internet as default browser the link is opened directly in browser

Some browsers, such as that one, have deeplink support disabled by default. Users can enable it in the browser app's settings.

Other browsers might simply not support deeplinks.

> Is there any other approach for this?

You have no means of forcing other developers to always open your app, if that is what you are asking. What Samsung Internet does is up to Samsung, for example.

Make sure that the Web page that is loaded has adequate instructions for users who wind up seeing that page.

Comment: But I've seen so many other emails that contain buttons which redirect the user to the app and it works regardless of what the default browser is. That's why I was hoping to be another way to do this.

Comment: @alexC: Look at the source of the email and see what the buttons do. If they use a custom scheme, you're welcome to try that, at the cost of the button not working on devices that lack your app.